# array with pairs

Tags: python, text-files

How to make a pair of an array with numbers?

```
array = []
subjects = raw_input("Subject: ")
array.append(subjects)
```

When I do this I will get an array like this:

```
["PSP","PMT","PMF"]
```

I wanted my output to be like this

```
[("PSP",1),("PMT",2),("PMF",3)]
```

How can I make it like that?

Comment: Actually I'd expect a `TypeError` because you're trying to use a list as a filename. But what should the file look like? CSV? One entry per line? What did you expect from `str(entries)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I expect that it would form one file for studentID with subjectCode inside and another one for subjectCode with studentID inside something like that

Comment: Why is `entries` even a list, then? You only ever add one thing to it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is actually a bigger picture from a whole lot of code so I kind of simplified it

Comment: Could you [edit] to give an actual [mcve]? The code you've posted doesn't actually recreate the issue you describe.

Comment: there are several way to get the desire output, you can use `zip` with `range`, or `enumerate` or keep track of a counter and append the desire tuple...

Comment: @Copperfield what do you mean? because I can't see it clearly what you mean with zip and range

Comment: for example with this`array=["PSP","PMT","PMF"]` you get the desire result with `zip(array,range(1,4))`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `p.write("\n".join(entires))`.

Alternatively, if you do not wish to hold the entire string in memory, you may as well loop over it like so:

```
for line in entries:
    p.write(line)
```